# iterating over time series in Python (numpy)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I would like to know the numpy equivalent of iterating over time series (any array is fine) to get calculations such as simple net and log returns.

In Matlab, I would use the following:

```
X = some T x N array

for i = 2:length(X)
    returns(i,:) = (returns(i,:) - returns(i-1,:))/returns(i-1,:)
end
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty similar in numpy:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

for i in range(1,len(X)):
    returns[i,:] = (returns[i,:] - returns[i-1,:]) / returns[i-1,:]
```

however note that you can realize the same computation as the `for` loop by using `np.diff(returns, axis=0) / returns[:-1]` (and similarly, MATLAB has the `diff()` function).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. However, doesn't python start indexing at 0 rather than 1? So i should be for i in range(1,len(X)) no ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping as you would in matlab, this is simple enough you can use a list comprehension:

```
array([(r - rprev) / rprev for rprev, r in zip(X, X[1:])])
```

`zip` is used to iterate over the rows of `X`, with an offset between them.
This is a rather general approach.
A more specific solution to this example is to use the `diff` function to find the difference between rows in 'X':

```
diff(X, axis=0) / X[:-1]
```

which will give the same results.